# Modify python regexp to match all floating point numbers instead of only the first one

Tags: python, regex, floating-point, match

I have a python function which uses a regular expression to match one (the first) floating point number in a given string and return the number.

How can I modify it (the regex) to generalize the function so that it returns instead a list with the all numbers in the string?

Here is a working demonstration:

```
    import re

    def extract_number(s,notfound='NOT_FOUND'):
        regex='[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?' # matching any floating point number 
        m = re.search(regex,s)
        if(m): val=m.group()
        else: val=notfound
        return val

    example='bla1.23bar4.5fuzz6.7cat8'

    print example
    print extract_number(example)
```

In this example, the output is:

`bla1.23bar4.5fuzz6.7cat8`
`1.23`

The modified function which I am looking for, let's call it extract_numbers (note the plural !), should output this:

`bla1.23bar4.5fuzz6.7cat8`
`[1.23, 4.5, 6.7, 8]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [re.findall](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
def extract_number(s,notfound='NOT_FOUND'):
    regex=r'[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?'
    return re.findall(regex,s)
```

Comment: To make this work you should make the group non-capturing: regex=r'[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?'

Comment: @user1069609 non-capturing means the submatch of a group `()` is NOT stored, see [Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your regex works for single numbers, you can use [`re.finditer`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```
re.finditer(r'[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?', 'bla1.23bar4.5fuzz6.7cat8')
```

so with

```
def extract_numbers(txt):
    for m in re.finditer(r'[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?', txt):
        yield float(m.group(0))
```

you can get all numbers:

```
list(extract_numbers('bla1.23bar4.5fuzz6.7cat8'))
```

returns

```
[1.23, 4.5, 6.7000000000000002, 8.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The main change is, use `findall`.

```
def extract_number(s, notfound='NOT_FOUND'):
    regex = '[-+]?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?' # matching any floating point number 
    m = re.findall(regex, s)
    if(m): val = m
    else: val = notfound
    return val
```

- I also changed your regex a bit, because your original returned only empty strings with `findall`, because of the capturing group.
- `m.group` is also not working anymore since `findall` return a list of strings, and `search` returns a `MatchObject`

Comment: Somehow it misses the last number (8) in my example 'bla1.23bar4.5fuzz6.7cat8'

Comment: @user1069609 you are right, I missed to make the fraction optional, its now fixed.